Prometheus doesn't scrape data from the /metrics endpoint
I'm following Microsoft's documentation for adding observability to .NET with OpenTelemetry. The issue is that Prometheus isn't able to scrape data from my ASP.NET Core Web API, although Jaeger is collecting data correctly.
I’m using a Docker Compose setup from a Microsoft repository: TaskWeaver Docker Compose.
Here’s what I suspect might be the problem: In my prometheus-config.yml, I've set the target to optl-collector:9464. However, since my ASP.NET Core Web API exposes metrics at https://localhost:5001/metrics, I think the target should be host.docker.internal:5000. This is because host.docker.internal would point to my machine’s localhost where the API is running, rather than within Docker. But if I change the target to host.docker.internal, I’m unsure of the role of optl-collector in this setup.
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddObservabilityServices(this IServiceCollection services, IHostEnvironment environment, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(services);
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(environment);
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(configuration);

        services.AddOpenTelemetry()
            .ConfigureResource(resource => resource
                .AddService(serviceName: environment.ApplicationName)
                .AddAttributes(new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    ["deployment.environment"] = environment.EnvironmentName
                }))
            .WithMetrics(metrics => metrics
                .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()
                .AddMeter(Metrics.SourceName)
                .AddMeter("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting")
                .AddMeter("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel")
                .AddPrometheusExporter())
            .WithTracing(tracing =>
            {
                tracing.AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation();
                tracing.AddHttpClientInstrumentation();
                tracing.AddSource(DistributedTracing.SourceName);
                
                // Export to Jaeger
                tracing.AddOtlpExporter(otlpOptions =>
                {
                    otlpOptions.Endpoint = new Uri("http://localhost:4317");
                });
            });

        return services;
    }

    public static IApplicationBuilder MapObservabilityEndpoints(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(app);

        app.UseOpenTelemetryPrometheusScrapingEndpoint();

        return app;
    }
}


docker-compose.yaml
version: '3.9'

services:

  optl-collector:
    image: otel/opentelemetry-collector:0.96.0
    command: ["--config=/etc/collector-config.yaml"]
    volumes:
      - ./collector-config.yaml:/etc/collector-config.yaml
    ports:
      - "4317:4317" # Expose the gRPC receiver port for the first collector
    depends_on:
      - jaeger

  jaeger:
    image: jaegertracing/all-in-one:1.54
    ports:
      - "16686:16686" # Jaeger UI

  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    ports:
      - "9090:9090" # Prometheus UI
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus-config.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    command: ["--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml"]
    depends_on:
      - optl-collector

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana-enterprise:latest
    ports:
      - "3000:3000" # Grafana UI
    environment:
      - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD=secret # You should change 'secret' to a password of your choosing
      - GF_USERS_ALLOW_SIGN_UP=false
    volumes:
      - grafana_data:/var/lib/grafana
    depends_on:
      - prometheus

volumes:
  grafana_data:

collector-config.yaml
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
        endpoint: 0.0.0.0:4317
      http:
        endpoint: 0.0.0.0:4318

exporters:
  debug:
    verbosity: detailed
  otlp:
    endpoint: "jaeger:4317"
    tls:
      insecure: true
  prometheus:
    endpoint: "0.0.0.0:9464"

service:
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [otlp]
    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [prometheus]
    logs:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [debug]

prometheus-config.yml
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: optl-collector
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ["optl-collector:9464"]


Yes, your ASP.NET appears to be configured to be scraped by a Prometheus server but the Docker Compose services represents a configuration in which an app pushes (!) metrics to the OpenTelemetry collector (via gRPC). and Prometheus scrapes the OpenTelemetry collector You want to either reconfigure your app to use the OpenTelemetry collector; or use a solution in which a Prometheus server is configured to scrape your app's /metrics endpoint.

@DazWilkin, thank you for the explanation! Which one do you think will be better?

It's difficult to answer without knowing more about your environment. I use Promethues and scrape endpoints extensively. OpenTelemetry is becoming popular and has a scope broader than just metrics.

@DazWilkin, I decided to keep the docker-compose as it is. Instead, I updated the code accordinly:  .WithMetrics(metrics => { ... if (otlpEndpoint != null) { metrics.AddOtlpExporter(otlpOptions => { otlpOptions.Endpoint = new Uri(otlpEndpoint); otlpOptions.Protocol = OpenTelemetry.Exporter.OtlpExportProtocol.Grpc; }); } }), and now both traces and metrics work

Please consider posting your updated code as an Answer. Stack overflow permits answering your own questions and, doing so provides future readers with a benefit

I decided to keep the docker-compose as it is. Instead, I updated the code accordinly:
.WithMetrics(metrics =>
{
    ...
    if (otlpEndpoint != null)
    {
        metrics.AddOtlpExporter(otlpOptions =>
        {
            otlpOptions.Endpoint = new Uri(otlpEndpoint);
            otlpOptions.Protocol = OpenTelemetry.Exporter.OtlpExportProtocol.Grpc;
        });
     }
}

